# Why Beautiful Soup is returning NONE instead of the div data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

```
response = requests.get(url="https://www.cbf.com.br/futebol-brasileiro/jogosdehoje/index")

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

data = soup.find('div', 'class="col-md-12"')

print(data)
```

Same when using find_all, when using extract it is just showing all html instead of just the div

Comment: I don't think the second argument is correct.  I believe it should be `soup.find('div', class_='col-md-12')`.